# HTTPS with PSK using Bouncy Castle

Tags: sockets, https, cryptography, bouncycastle, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have established a secure socket connection using the Bouncy Castle Pre-Shared Key.
I would like to know how to use this socket connection to send my http request securely.
I am using a apache http client for sending my http request.

IN short, I have to use https but with PSK Implementation of Bouncy Castle. It is easy to create a socket connection with PSK BC, but how to redirect http request through it ?

Comment: Could [this](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html#setSSLSocketFactory(org.apache.http.conn.socket.LayeredConnectionSocketFactory)) work? The interface `LayeredConnectionSocketFactory` returns just a Socket, so it should be easy to implement.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes My understanding of LayeredConnectionSocketFactory is not good. I do not understand how to integrate it with my PSK Bouncy Castle authentication? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: My understanding is we can not directly send Http Request to Bouncy Castle PSK based socket as it does not understand HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Used the conventional method of routing http message.
Once the TLS PSK socket connection is established, the http request is sent by writing HTTP message to the socket connection in http standard, that involves writing http Request Line first, followed by Request Headers, and a new line followed with the content, if any.
Then, at the server side, read the decrypted Http Request in the reverse direction.

Basically, had to implement the httpClient and httpServer using Socket Connection from basic.